# Carrierwave Mongoid validation of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I cant figure out how to validate that carrierwave has uploaded a document to my mongoid object.

i have a Document Class

```
class Content::Document < Content

  mount_uploader :attachment, DocumentUploader   

  field :attachable_id
  field :attachable_type
end
```

and an uploader:

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/mongoid'
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage = :filesystem
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end          

  def extension_white_list
    %w(doc docx xls xlsx ppt pptx pdf )
  end
```

i would like to validate that the upload exists and that it matches the white list else through a standard validation error

this is on Rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you don't need to do that since this behaviour is already tested in carrierwave specs itself.

You can test your uploaders in isolation, using Carrierwave test helpers. E.g. I would just write a spec like

```
attachment_uploader.extension_white_list.should =~ %w(doc docx xls xlsx ppt pptx pdf)
```

But if you insist on testing that I would suggest using [FakeFS](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) to stub filesystem and then check with

```
File.exists? document.attachment.current_path
```

whether attachment has been created.

Answer (score 2):

While it's true that Carrierwave does have extensive tests, you could test for validity with something like this:

```
it "is valid with valid attributes" do
    file_bytes = File.open("spec/binary/avatar.png")
    valid_attrs = {:name => "foo", :description => "bar", :avatar => file_bytes}
    user = User.new(valid_attrs)
    user.should be_valid
  end
```

Hope that helps!